# Angularjs Google charts event listener

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

I am trying to make my google chart interactive using angularjs. I am using this AngularJs Google Chart directive https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart 
I tried several options to add Listener by going through some examples.

```
$scope.selectListener = google.visualization.events.addListener($scope.chart, 'select', function () {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
          var selectedItem = $scope.chart.getSelection()[0];
          if (selectedItem) {
            var topping = $scope.chart.data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            alert('The user selected ' );
          }
     })

 });
```

I am seeing these errors in my browser

> Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$interpolate/interr?p0=%24scope.chartObje…json%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20Converting%20circular%20structure%20to%20JSON
>       at Error (native)

Can someone please help me with an example how to make google chart interactive using angularjs?

Here is some more information which I would like to share:

```
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;

    var chdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chdata.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    chdata.addColumn('number', 'Passed');
   chdata.addColumn('number', 'Failed');
    for( var i=0; i<queueDet.length; i++){
    chdata.addRow([queueDet[i].rundate, {v: queueDet[i].passedTestCount, f: queueDet[i].buildTag}, {v: queueDet[i].failedTestCount}]);
    }
```

In this column chart I would like to make those columns interactive and when I click Passed column, would like to make an $http call by passing queueDet[i].buildTag to get additional details and render them in a table.

Comment: I contribute to this project regularly.  I can answer you're question, but you're not saying much about what you are trying to achieve.  See my blog post on hiding a series for an example of adding interactive functionality with angular-Google-chart. http://nicholasbering.ca/angularjs/2014/08/16/agc-hide-series/

Comment: I edited few more details and if you can share any code sample that would be great